# dpkg-query placeholders "Filename", "MD5sum" and "Size" are always empty

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I'm currently trying to get some info about the installed pakages und systems that use `dpkg`. So I tried to use `dpkg-query`. Most placeholders work fine and I get what I need, however I noticed that the placeholders `Filename`, `MD5sum` and `Size` are always empty.

Simple command to see the issue:

```
dpkg-query -W -f '"location":"${Filename}","md5":"${MD5sum}","size":"${Size}"\\n'
```

This will result in loads of lines of just

```
"location":"","md5":"","size":""
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [the manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg-query.1), these fields are “internal, front-end related”. In fact they’re only used in `dselect`.

This means you can’t rely on them in `dpkg-query`, by default. They correspond to values stored in the “available” database, `/var/lib/dpkg/available`; `dpkg-query` by default only considers `/var/lib/dpkg/status` nowadays. You can add the `--load-avail` option to merge the information from the “available” database, in theory — but that requires using `dselect` as your package installation tool, since `/var/lib/dpkg/available` is only kept up-to-date by `dselect`. If you use APT this won’t work, as described in the documentation for the `-p` command:

> Users of APT-based frontends should use `apt-cache show package-name` instead as the `available` file is only kept up-to-date when using `dselect`.

It might help if I expand a bit on the meaning of the fields: `Filename`, `MD5sum` and `Size` (and `MSDOS-Filename`) all give information on the file containing a package (its filename, checksum and size). They aren’t germane to the packages themselves, so the `status` database doesn’t need them and doesn’t store them. A package, installed or otherwise, remains the same regardless of where its package file lives and what its characteristics are. That information is only useful for front-ends which retrieve packages and provide them to `dpkg`.

Comment: I saw these in the manpages, however could not find any reference as to what `internal` and `front-end related` mean. Also according to said mainpage they should be available.

Comment: That isn't really clear from the man page. The man states that (emphasis mine) "*The following fields are recognized but they are not necessarily available in the status file (**only internal fields** or fields stored in the binary package **end up in it**)*" which would suggest that, contrary to what your answer states, it's the internal fields that will be included.

Comment: @terdon right, I wrote my answer based on the source code, not the documentation ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt is there a format option for `apt-cache show` too? Else the manipulation of the texts is gonna be a nightmare...

Comment: @BrainStone not with `apt-cache`, but the output follows RFC 822 and is *designed* to be parsed. If you want a controllable format using APT-based tools, look at `aptitude search` and its `-F` option.

Comment: I see. Looks like I need to do a lot more to end up with a nice JSON file. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464118/escape-dpkg-query-placeholders is very realted...

Comment: Because the issues are not JSON specific. And this question in particular is unrelated to the final format.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`grep-available`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/dctrl-tools/grep-available.1.en.html) tool instead (or more better `grep-aptavail`  as mentioned [@Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)) :

```
grep-available -s  Filename,MD5sum,size -PX <package_name>
```

Example:

```
grep-available -s  Filename,MD5sum,size -PX dpkg
```

sample output:

```
Filename: pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.18.24_amd64.deb
MD5sum: 5553b3fac608f5c4f9fa3ddbff18c2c5
Size: 2106696
```

Comment: Or better yet in most cases, `grep-aptavail`.

Comment: I think this is a great answer for the general public, but not for me, as I need a portable solution. (That's why I won't accept it)